# Regex - lookahead greedy but optionnal

Tags: php, regex

Need help with a regex, I have spent hours trying in every direction but I cannot seem to figure it out...
I have firmware file names like those :

- sw_smv-e10200_400_800_6.0.5.2-50o--HF157793_770720_50o_2-prod.sig
- sw_smv-e10200_400_800_6.0.5.2-50o_761649-prod.sig
- sw_e10200_400_800_6.0.1.8_146o_60ksso_1-prod.bin.sig
- sw_smv-e10200_400_800_6.0.1.8_164o_600296-prod.sig

I want to extract clean version numbers like:

- 6.0.5.2-50o--HF157793(_50o)_2
- 6.0.5.2-50o
- 6.0.1.8_146o_60ksso_1
- 6.0.1.8_164o

here is the regex I had so far:

```
(e10200_400_800_)(.*)(_[0-9]{6})(.*)?-(prod|stdeb)
```

but that seems to give me trouble with the ksso which does not have the _[0-9]{6} matching and simply fails to return anything...
If I add a ? to it, then I simply do exclude it, even when playing on lazyness / greediness like

```
(e10200_400_800_)(.*?)(_[0-9]{6})?+(.*?)?-(prod|stdeb)
```

I also tried to play with lookahead / lookbehind but could not get a good combination...

Anyone has a solution for me?

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: Why `6.0.1.8_164o` instead of `6.0.1.8_164o_600296` in the last line?

Comment: just like for line number 2, I am just trying to get a clean version name, excluding the internal build number such as 600296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

`([0-9]+\..+?)(?(?=_\d{6})_\d{6}|(_[^_-]+?))(?:_\d{6}|(_.*?))?(?:-prod|-stdeb)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR6tV2/3).

This has been a mindbreaker. Conditional expression and alternative lists are key here. Your required strings are sum total of all the 3 groups.

```
MATCH 1
1.  [22-43] `6.0.5.2-50o--HF157793`
2.  EMPTY
3.  [50-56] `_50o_2`
MATCH 2
1.  [88-99] `6.0.5.2-50o`
2.  EMPTY
3.  EMPTY
MATCH 3
1.  [138-145]   `6.0.1.8`
2.  [145-150]   `_146o`
3.  [150-159]   `_60ksso_1`
MATCH 4
1.  [195-202]   `6.0.1.8`
2.  [202-207]   `_164o`
3.  EMPTY
```

Comment: This is not perfectly what I was looking for. In your example, the first result is getting the build number "770720" part of the match, which I want to exclude. Should I actually do 2 pass: filter most of the stuff then get rid of the _\d{6} ?

Comment: @Fabien: It looks like I got the culprit with conditional expression, lazy quantificators and alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This works on your samples  `(?<=_)(\d+\.(?:(?!_\d{6}).)+)(?:_\d{6})?(.*)(?=-(?:prod|stdeb))`

The version is capture group 1 catted with group 2.

[Formatted](http://regexformat.com):

```
 (?<= _ )                      # Lookbehind '_'
 (                             # (1 start), Version number  'digit(s) dot plus greedy anything(s)'
      \d+ \.
      (?:
           (?! _ \d{6} )                 # not '_ \d{6}' anywhere
           . 
      )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?: _ \d{6} )?                # optional '_666666'
 ( .* )                        # (2), Optional remainder greedy anything(s)
 (?=                           # Lookahead
      -                             # '-'
      (?: prod | stdeb )            # 'prod' or 'stdeb'
 )
```

Output:

```
  **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 23 , len 34 ) 
 6.0.5.2-50o--HF157793_770720_50o_2  
  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 23 , len 21 ) 
 6.0.5.2-50o--HF157793  
  **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 51 , len 6 ) 
 _50o_2  

 --------

  **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 91 , len 18 ) 
 6.0.5.2-50o_761649  
  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 91 , len 11 ) 
 6.0.5.2-50o  
  **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 109 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

 --------

  **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 139 , len 21 ) 
 6.0.1.8_146o_60ksso_1  
  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 139 , len 21 ) 
 6.0.1.8_146o_60ksso_1  
  **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 160 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

 --------

  **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 198 , len 19 ) 
 6.0.1.8_164o_600296  
  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 198 , len 12 ) 
 6.0.1.8_164o  
  **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 217 , len 0 )  EMPTY
```

Comment: same here, it does match 770720 in the first string: 6.0.5.2-50o--HF157793_770720_50o_2. It should exclude it even if it returns 2 matches

Answer (score 0):

Your files can have dots in name (most important part)?
If don't, you can try use this

```
[0-9]\..+(?=-prod|-stdeb)
```

It worked for examples that you gave https://regex101.com/r/hX8eX4/1

Answer (score 0):

this seem to work:

```
(([0-9]\..+)(?:(?>_\d{6}))(.*)|([0-9]\..+)(?:(?!\d{6})))(?=-prod|-stdeb)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eW2yT1/1)
Got the result I want in match [2] + [3], or in [4]

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool you're looking for is a [conditional group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

```
e10200_400_800_\K\d+(?:\.\d+)+[_-]\d+[a-z](?(?!_\d{6}-)[^.]*(?=-prod|-stdeb))
```

Here's the conditional:

```
(?(?!_\d{6}-)[^.]*(?=-prod|-stdeb))
```

If the next thing in the string doesn't match `_\d{6}-`, continue matching until you reach a point where the next thing is `-prod` or `-stdeb`.  Otherwise, stop matching right here.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eW2yT1/2)

I also used `\K`, the poor man's lookbehind:

```
e10200_400_800_\K
```

That allows me to match the `e10200_400_800_` prefix to make sure the match starts at the right place, but doesn't include the prefix in the match.  I could have used an actual lookbehind for this, but `\K` is neater and much more flexible.